# Transforming the Extrinsic Curvature Tensor With a Change in the Temporal Variable

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus

When the extrinsic curvature tensor of General Relativity is defined as $K_{ij}=\frac{1}{2\alpha}(\triangledown_i\beta_j+\triangledown_j\beta_i-\frac{\partial g_{ij}}{\partial t})$, the indices are strictly spatial, which means that transforming the tensor would look like $K_{\hat{i}\hat{j}}=\frac{\partial i}{\partial\hat{i}}\frac{\partial j}{\partial\hat{j}}K_{ij}$. What I'm confused about is, if the temporal variable is changed  along with the spatial variables(s), is doing $K_{\hat{i}\hat{j}}=\frac{\partial i}{\partial\hat{i}}\frac{\partial j}{\partial\hat{j}}K_{ij}$ sufficient? I'm thinking yes, because if $(x^0,x^1)$$\rightarrow$$(x^\hat{0},x^\hat{1})$, then $\frac{\partial x^1}{\partial \hat{x^1}}$ may be different than if just $x^1$$\rightarrow$$x^\hat{1}$, but I'm not sure, because, for instance, what is only the temporal variable is changed? Then it would just be $\frac{\partial x^1}{\partial x^1}$.

Comment: The definition $K_{ab}=-(1/2)\mathscr{L}_{\textbf{n}}h_{ab}$ where $h_{ab}=g_{ab}+n_an_b$, is manifestly covariant

Comment: Are all of the indices in both the lie derivative and $h_{ab}$ capable of being temporal? I'm assuming $a$ and $b$ have to be spatial, because they are next to $K$.

Comment: a, b are space-time components and not just the space components. If $n_a=(-N, 0,0,0) $,  where $N$ is the lapse function, then for spatial components : $g_{ij}=h_{ij}$

Comment: So there can be a $K_{tt}$ (if $x^0=t$)?

Comment: Yes. There can be non-zero tt, ti components for these quantities but the important idea here is that the projection of $K_{ab}$ along $n_a$ is zero: $K_{ab}n^a=0$. Spatial components are defined here to be those directions orthogonal to $n$. You may read more about this from, say, chapter 12 from "Gravitatioan Foundations and Frontiers" by T.Padmanabhan

Comment: Weird. I thought that there could only be $K_{ij}$, per se. So, if someone were to change between, say classical Schwarzschild metric to Eddington-Finkelstein metric, where the time coordinate is different, the lie derivative way would be the best way to find $K_{ij}$?